# how to create the div on the fly in javascript / jquery in this way

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have asp.net mvc 2 application where i have a scenario as follows:
I want to create the parent div and in side it want to create n-number of divs with controls.like

```
    for(j=0;j<parentCount;j++)
    {
    //Create the parent div
      for(i=0;i<childDivCount;i++)
    {
    //create child div, with controls (like radio,checkboxes).and attach to parentDiv
    }
//Attach parent div to document.
    }
```

how to achieve this .

**Edited:**
i am bit get satisfaction with answers. but when i am using getJson in each loop as:

```
  //$.getJSON(url1,,function(data1){
    //for each item in data1 :-
         for(j=0;j<parentCount;j++)
              {
                  //Create the parent div 
                  //$.getJSON(url2,,function(data2){
//**** here j automatically get j++ , why ? ****//
                  //For each item in data2 :-
                  for(i=0;i<childDivCount;i++)
                 {
                     //create child div, with controls (like radio,checkboxes).and attach to     parentDiv
                  }

               });
            //Attach parent div to document.
                }
        });
```

when entering for getJson of data2 (subloop) var j get automatically incremented. why that should be ?

**Edited:-**
in fact i want to create the question-answer scenario. since in first getJson call i am getting all questions and then in sub getJson call i am getting answers of each question. for each question i am creating div as parent div , and for its answers appending parent div with answers child div. thats all. i didn't wanted to use user control here , so i used the json-jquery combination  to generate scenario. this is what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it :).

```
for (j=0;j<parentCount;j++)
{
  parentDiv = $('<div />');

  for (i=0;i<childDivCount;i++)
  {
    childDiv = $('<div />');
    parentDiv.append(childDiv);
  }

  someElementInDocument.append(parentDiv);
}
```

Comment: well this should be ok, i am getting issue here , see my question again, edit part basically

Comment: If I understand you correctly I'd change the first for with $.each on the data.

Comment: @ Kaltas , i tried it with $.each. but unfortunately it did not sound anything there. so i applied simple for loop instead of the each(). what to do there

Comment: OK I think I'm not sure what you want to accomplish there. Can you escribe it in more detail?

Comment: yep. please review question again, i explained my scenario

Comment: OK I understand now. First thing is that you should get all data in one AJAX request and not do new request for each of questions. Second thing is that while I don't know your JSON responses what you need to do is to loop through the data as they do it in examples on this jQuery documentation page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do the trick (haven't tried to run but it should be mostly right).

```
for(j=0;j<parentCount;j++)
{
    //Create the parent div
    $('body').append('<div id="parent-div">');
    for(i=0;i<childDivCount;i++)
    {
        //create child div, with controls (like radio,checkboxes).and attach to parentDiv
         $('#parent-div').append('<select>...</select>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review my question again. have an issue